# Overflow scrolling not scrolling left

Tags: css, overflow, viewport

I have a horizontal tab list which is centered at Tab 2 and tab 3 (out of 4+ tabs). I added the code below to create horizontal scrolling and removed the scrollbar.

```
overflow-x: auto;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
scrollbar-width: none;
```

My issue is that the tabs only scroll right towards tab 4, they are not scrolling left to tab 1 at all. Also I have decorations on the tabs like shadow and border, using overflow: auto is removing them/ messing with them somehow.

[image: problem]

Is overflow the wrong thing to use here or am I using it wrong?